# Scipy minimize has a problem with shapes even when they are right

Tags: python, scipy

I'm implementing a classic logistic regresion algorithm on python and I've been trying to optimize the cost function with `optimize.minimize` but i'm getting an error related to the shapes. However, i'm completely sure the dimensions are right. Here's my code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

def sig(z):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-z))

def h(X,theta):
    return sig(np.dot(X,theta))

def cost(X,y,theta):
    return -np.dot(np.log(h(X,theta)).T,y)-np.dot(1-np.log(h(X,theta)).T,1-y)

def grad(X,y,theta):
    return np.dot(X.T,h(X,theta)-y)

X=np.ones((10,3))
theta=np.zeros(X.shape[1])
y=np.ones(10)

opt=optimize.minimize(cost,theta,jac=grad,args=(X,y),method='CG')
```

And I get this error

```
   File "C:/Users/Neso/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 8, in h
    return sig(np.dot(X,theta))

  ValueError: shapes (3,) and (10,) not aligned: 3 (dim 0) != 10 (dim 0)
```

But `X` is (10,3) and `theta` is (3,0) so there should be no problem with `np.dot(X,theta)`. I even can call all the methods without problem. I have heard `optimize.minimize` is very sensitive when the inputs are matrices and vectors, but i don't know what to do in this case. Any suggestions? Thanks
        `

Comment: When calling `cost` `minimize` passes `(theta, X, y)`.  The minimization variable comes first, the `args` after.  Things might be clearer if you used different names for variables in the global environment and inside the functions.  Arguments are passed by position, not by name.  The cost call gets: `cost( a(3,), a(10,3), a(10,))`.

Comment: You're a genius, it works perfectly. Thank you